# I cannot find the set these bags of Lego bricks belong to - lots of greys and dark reds

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I cannot find the set these bags of Lego bricks belong to.
Can anyone help?

[image: lots of greys and dark reds]

Answer (score 6):

The bottom polybag contains 92946 in light bluish gray, 32523 in light bluish gray, and 3666 in tan. [That combination](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=92946&itemSeq1=1&colorID1=86&itemNo2=32523&itemSeq2=1&colorID2=86&itemNo3=3666&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=2&in=S) of parts appears only in one set: [75243 Star Wars' Slave I, 20th anniversary edition](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75243-1).

Answer (score 4):

Top right polybag [appears to be](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=3062b&itemSeq1=1&colorID1=59&itemNo2=2412b&itemSeq2=1&colorID2=17&itemNo3=&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=&in=S) from one of two Death Star - UCS sets: [10188](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10188-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) or [75159](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75159-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Comment: These bags aren't all from the same set. [32523 in light grey](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=32523&colorID=86&in=A) is visible in the lower bag and isn't in either of those Death Stars.

Comment: @FredricShope thanks for noticing. I've updated the answer accordingly.